# Mocked Jest callback method not called

Tags: node.js, callback, jestjs

I'm testing the NodeJS function/module below using jestjs

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
function read(filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, filename), { encoding: "utf-8" }, callback);
}

module.exports = {
  read,
};
```

The first test is:

```js
  test("callback data returned is correct", (done) => {
    function callback(err, data) {
      try {
        expect(data).toBe("1");
        done();
      } catch (err) {
        done(err);
      }
    }
    read("./test", callback);
  });
```

and is succesful (I have an actual real `test` file with the contents being `1`.

The second one is a bit trickier. Since I'm providing a mockCallback function to `read`, **why** isn't the callback called?

```js
const { read } = require("./callback");

describe("callback testing", () => {
  test("callback is called", (done) => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn((err, data) => data);
    read("./test", mockCallback);
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

The test fails and while inspecting the mock function it seems it wasn't called.

I also tried adding the following in order to mock `fs.readFile`, without much success:

```js
const mock = require("mock-fs");
const fs = require("fs");
jest.mock("fs");
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock({
      test: "1",
    });
  });
```

I'd like a solution that mocks the least of the dependant methods and an explanation as to why isn't the callback run.

Comment: Yes, it's because that's an asynchronous operation. What kind of test are you trying to write, do you want it to read an actual file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. For the purpose of this test, I'd like to read the actual file. (updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mock `fs.readFile` method and trigger the callback in your test case.

E.g.

`callback.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function read(filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, filename), { encoding: 'utf-8' }, callback);
}

module.exports = {
  read,
};
```

`callback.test.js`:

```js
const { read } = require('./callback');
const fs = require('fs');

describe('callback testing', () => {
  test('callback is called', () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn();
    const mockData = 'mock file data';
    const mockReadFile = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFile').mockImplementationOnce((filename, options, callback) => {
      callback(null, mockData);
    });
    read('./test', mockCallback);
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockReadFile).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(String), { encoding: 'utf-8' }, mockCallback);
    mockReadFile.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65361608/callback.test.js
  callback testing
    ✓ callback is called (3 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 callback.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.992 s, estimated 5 s
```

Comment: ignoring `fs` . assuming it's any other custom function we write, would it be possible to achieve the same without ignoring the function but only the callback ?